# Proof Without contradiction $x^2 = 2$ has no rational solutions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, rational-numbers

I am in the process of learning real analysis and I was wondering if there was a way to prove no $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfies $x^2 = 2$ without a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Do you get to use unique factorization?

Comment: Yes you can. As long as it is not too high level I am open to hearing it.

Comment: @BrianTung ...but then you'd need to provide a proof of unique factorization that's not by contradiction either.

Comment: @Sam: Plausibly, but that depends on who's asking. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "without contradiction" - when we reduce proofs of irrationality to their most basic form, they look like:

> Let $p/q$ be any rational number. We will show that $(p/q)^2$ is not $2$.

The trouble is "it's not $2$" is often *defined* to mean "we could derive a contradiction if it were equal to $2$." More or less, one talks about proof by contradiction when a contradiction is used to prove a statement that is *not* the negation of some other statement (e.g. "all trees have one less edge than vertex") - where essentially we try to prove this statement by saying "it's not true that not all trees have one less edge than vertex" and then cancelling the two "nots" (which is not valid in intuitionistic logic).

The usual proof of this is a direct proof of a negated statement, not a proof by contradiction. In particular, consider the argument:

> Let $p/q$ be a rational number. We claim that assuming $(p/q)^2=2$ leads to a contradiction. To see this, first reduce $p/q$ to a fraction $p'/q'$ with coprime numerator and denominator. Note $(p')^2 = 2(q')^2$. Therefore $p'$ must be even so $p'=2r$. Then note $2r^2 = (q')^2$. So $q'$ must be even. This creates a contradiction since $2$ divides both $p'$ and $q'$.

While this formalizes in different ways depending on your formal system, you can think of it as a recipe that says "Give me any rational number and allow me to assume it is $\sqrt{2}$. I will give back a contradiction" - which is exactly what it means to show that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, with no fancy steps like double negation elimination involved.

In other words: our goal was to define a sort of "function" that takes two inputs:

1. A rational number $x$
2. The assumption that $x=\sqrt{2}$.

and gives as output a contradiction. That is what our proof describes. (For reference: this particular interpretation as a function is in line with a branch of logic known as *type theory*)

Comment: I think with a relatively small adjustment you should be able to structure this as: Let $x$ be any rational number; and from that conclude that $x^2 \ne 2$, all without relying on "2. The assumption that $x=\sqrt{2}$".

Comment: @paw88789 You can absolutely do that - which proves the rather nicer statement "$2$ lacks a rational square root." Of course, proving $x^2\neq 2$ is really just showing that assuming $x^2=2$ leads to a contradiction. (...although, what I intentionally did not point out in this answer: you can hide these contradictions in lemmas - and you can get in all the important content of your proof without mentioning contradiction, maybe just plugging into a few little lemmas that do involve a contradiction at the very end)

Comment: Just an aside on contradiction in intuitionistic logic. If $P$ gives a contradiction, we conclude $\neg P$, just as in classical logic, so we're fine if we wanted to prove something of the form $\neg P$. If $\neg P$ gives a contradiction, we conclude $\neg\neg P$, which doesn't simplify to $P$ as in classical logic, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Only irrational numbers have infinite continued fraction expansions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction for more information about continued fractions.

We can write $\sqrt{2}$ as $[1,2,2,2,2,\ldots]$ and therefore it is irrational.

**Alternative method using some ring theory:**

By Eisenstein's Criterion, the polynomial $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Gauss' Lemma. Hence $x^2-2$ has no rational solutions.

Comment: is this the only other method?

Comment: This uses a questionable definition of "irrational" - it's certainly *true* that irrational numbers are those that have infinite continued fraction expansions, but that sounds like a theorem being subtly introduced as a definition.

Comment: Don't you also need to prove sqrt(2) can be represented like that?

Comment: That doesn’t show $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. The converse does though.

Comment: Trying to prove irrational without contradiction is rather hard in general, so you're going to have to resort to some heavier machinery.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will accept your answer once the waiting period is finished.

Comment: I have adjusted the answer to reflect that this is a theorem, rather than a definition, as noted by @MiloBrandt

Comment: It still doesn’t prove $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. If you’d said any number with an infinite continued fraction expansion is irrational, that would work

Comment: why doesn't it?

Comment: It’s like saying:  any number divisible by $6$ is divisible by $3$. Since $9$ is divisible by $3$, $9$ is divisible by $6$

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Simple_Infinite_Continued_Fraction_Converges_to_Irrational_Number for a proof that this method is correct.

Comment: You’re clearly missing the point. Your answer and that statement are the opposite.

Comment: I don't see what you're getting at here. $\sqrt{2}$ is the value of an infinite continued fraction, and therefore must be irrational.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow The method is correct, certainly.  What Loobear23 is driving at is simply that you should have said something like, "Only irrational numbers have infinite continued fraction representations."

Comment: I understand. I have adjusted the answer.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow The proofwiki citation you give, itself appears to be a proof by contradiction.  (So also does the Wikipedia Proof of Eisenstein's criterion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Basic_proof )

Comment: Gauss' Lemma can be proved without contradiction, so I suppose you could adjust the argument for $x^2-2$ being irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ without using contradiction. Some would argue that it is clear that $x^2-2$ has no solutions over $\mathbb{Z}$.